# Why does TypeScript compiler wraps functions in (0, module.fn)?

Tags: typescript, tsc

I've noticed that TypeScript converts this type of code:

```js
import { _, defaultLocale } from '../locale';
const test = _('testing');
```

To this:

```js
const locale_1 = require("../locale");
const test = (0, locale_1._)('testing');
```

In particular it wraps the function call in `(0, module.fn)()`. Any idea what it means or why it's doing this?